# How to find elements without using the tag attribute?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
image = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@class,'ui_qtext')]")
copy = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[contains(@class,'ui_qtext')]")
```

I have this two elements with different tag_names. How do i locate them without the tag_name? Or how do i "combine" this two? Both have the same class_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the dependency on the *tagNames* you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  image_copy = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'ui_qtext')]")
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  image_copy = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ui_qtext")
  ```