# How to xpath two different tags in selenium python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, class, selenium-chromedriver

```
<span class="ui_qtext_rendered_qtext">
    <p class="ui_qtext_para u-ltr u-text-align--start">
    <div class="ui_qtext_image_outer">
        <div class="ui_qtext_image_wrapper">
            <img class="landscape ui_qtext_image zoomable_in zoomable_in_feed" 
            src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-" 
            master_src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-" 
            master_w="2400" master_h="1260">
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="ui_qtext_para u-ltr u-text-align--start">"It’s all doable, but 
    it’s technically very difficult."</p>
    <p class="qtext_citation_lead">Footnotes</p>
    <p class="citation" id="KLPFK">
        <a href="#cite-KLPFK" class="citation_index">[1] </a>
        <span class="qlink_container">
            <a href="https://futurism.com/the-byte/bionic-eye-prototype" 
            rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank" onclick="return 
            Q.openUrl(this, 184353372);" class="external_link" data-qt-
            tooltip="futurism.com">This experimental bionic eye could help the 
            blind see</a>
        </span>
    </p>
</span>
```

I want both img and p tags in the same xpath

So i did this

```
copy = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'ui_qtext')]")
```

but i doesnt work because img has to be exact

Comment: You could try an or operation in xpath which is done by using the | character. So something like `//p[contains(@class,'ui_qtext')]|//img[contains(@class,'ui_qtext')]`

Comment: How did you dig out `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'ui_qtext')]")`? Are you referring to your [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62109805/how-to-find-elements-without-using-the-tag-attribute/62109943#62109943) where you have taken the help in the form of a canonical answer and deleted the question without giving any credit?

Comment: Yeah i am sorry. I undeleted it and accepted the answer because i cant upvote it.